# Create Thumbnail from Office Files, Videos, Images with PHP

Tags: php, image, video, ms-office, thumbnails

My company is building an internal app where they need to upload videos (most probably almost all of them in MP4 format), PDF files, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Images (jpg, png, etc) and then it should be able to make a thumbnail out of it. I have had a look at other questions here but they are too old and some of the recommended services were too old and not being updated.

I would love to know your suggestions. I heard that with Images I might be able to use ImageMagik, and also heard of FFMPEG once that could retrieve a still image from a video (I saw this when I tried to build a site with Drupal).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question: what have you actually looked at so far, and what problems have you encountered... or are you simply wanting someone to give you a solution?

Comment: Hi Mark Baker, yes sorry it is a bit of a broad question. I have been looking all over the internet and even in StackOverflow for any possible solution (maybe a suggested service) that I can go on my own to investigate and see if it solves the problem my company is facing currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command to create thumbnails from videos with ffmpeg:

```
/path/to/ffpeg -i /path/to/video_file -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -r 1 -ss <time> -s <size> -y /path/to/save_image.jpg
# <time> with format hh:mm:ss
# <size> with format WIDTHxHEIGHT (ex: 240x320)
```